# FastAPI redirect after background task has finished

Tags: web-services, fastapi, background-task

I have an endpoint which triggers a process in FastAPI.
The process takes several minutes and produces a .csv file that can later be donwloaded by the users.

How can I return a message saying that the process is running and redirecting the users to the download page AFTER the process has finished.

So far I am returning an HTML response pointing to the Downloads page but if the users click on it before the process has finished they may not get the correct results:

```
@router.post("/run")
async def run(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks) -> HTMLResponse:
    """
    1. Run model.
    2. Retrieve output file.
    """

    background_tasks.add_task(optimization_process)

    content = """
<label for="file">Generating results:</label><br>
<progress id="file" max="100" value="70"> 70% </progress><br>
<body> Visit <a href="./get-results">result page</a> to get the results </body>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=content)
```

I am looking to improve this setup by informing the users that the process has started and redirecting AFTER the successful run of optimization_process.